# OSGi and performance?

Tags: java, performance, osgi

Is `OSGi` adapted for high performance application servers?

`OSGi` helps a lot to produce highly modular applications but what is the impact on performance since the model of execution is different than regular Java applications (since I understand that the `OSGi` applications run on specific platform, as `Apache Felix`).

What are your experiences with the different implementations in term of performance?

Thanks

Comment: What is the meaning of adapted?

Comment: @Edmondo1984 I meant, do you recommend using OSGi for high performance application servers.

Answer (score 8):

In my experience, moving applications from non-OSGi to an OSGi environment (using Felix) has made no impact on performance. Each build I produce is subjected to stress tests; the results of the stress tests have indicated no drop in performance.

It might depend on what your application does. I'll discount *explicit* OSGi concepts such as services as such new code will need your own testing and I'm assuming you're asking what the impact is on existing POJO code.

The *implicit* impact of an OSGi environment is mainly on class loading. As you probably know, OSGi mandates separate class loaders for each bundle, and provides a way of *wiring* code in bundles to dependencies in other bundles. When a class in a bundle calls a class in a different bundle, it is the second bundle's classloader that is responsible for loading that second class class.

It *might be* (but probably won't be) that this class loading logic consumes a little extra work than the default class loaders used in a vanilla Java environment. However, unless your code is itself re-creating and reloading classes constantly, which is unlikely, any performance impact is likely to be negligible. And in any case, that's just a theoretical possibility. It's up to the implementation you choose to be as efficient as possible.

There is also a small impact on memory footprint. It's best to take a heap dump and use something like mat to analyse this.

You'll spend much more time getting your head around OSGi conceptually, differences between OSGi containers, tools, version management and more than you will waiting for classes to load, believe me ;)

Comment: The fact that there are more classloaders in OSGi doesn't necessarily mean it's going to be slower. In fact if you follow through with the thought process that each bundle has it's own classloader, it also means that each bundle only has to perform classloader lookups from a subset of resources that is an (few) order(s) of magnitude smaller than the traditional java classpath size. Each bundle should be able to do it's class loading very quickly and so it's hard to use the "many classloaders" arg as a downside when considering performance. Each bundle will actually be far more nimble.

Comment: I didn't mean to suggest it was going to be slower. I said 'It might be that this class loading logic consumes a little extra work'. Similarly, it might also be that there's less work. I was trying to be non-committal, because no actual answer can be given either way unless the OSGi implementation is known.

Answer (score 5):

OSGi can result in a very small performance increase due to faster classloading. It can also result in a very small increase in memory consumption due to multiple classloaders.

Contrary to the assertion in your question: **OSGi does not change the Java execution model**.

Answer (score 3):

On the impact of the classloading performance, I believe in general the impact of OSGi vs. the traditional classloading model is not very big.

I think there are two factors that go for and against OSGi. There is up front "penalty" you incur you don't normally, and that is the resolution phase. The bundles need to be resolved, and their dependencies wired. There are other complicating factors such as DynamicImport-Package, etc.

There is then the actual classloading performance. This is where OSGi probably wins. In case of OSGi classloading, it is a pretty straightforward delegation on already wired dependencies. In case of the traditional classloading, this would be a linear search against your global classpath. This would apply for every single class you load.

Answer (score 2):

You may have to count with certain start-up time of the framework, but in the runtime it has basically zero impact on performance since in a nutshell it's just about class loading.

Quite a lot of modern application servers use OSGi implementations as a basis (e.g. JBoss, WebSphere, WebLogic, GlassFish) so you may be sure it's reliable and performs well. 
Please see this reference list: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSGi#Projects_using_OSGi

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is no performance penalty unless you take class loading into account but that only happend when you add new modules (services) or start the framework. Maybe the fact that designing an applicatoin to be modulirized, would cause some drop in performance compared to other architectures, but that is usually not taken into account since this is java and the fact that you can make an application that can work 24/7 wich is the whole purpose of OSGi then you sure can sacrifice that little bit of performcance (i would say).

Comment: Every layer added cost some performance, this is usually true in most cases. Designing your application to be higly modulirized brings lots of benefits in terms of design and maintainance, but the level of abstraction that is added cost some amount of performance in terms of execution time and space. Although in most applications, specially object oriented application having a good design and high maintanability its considered better than a few millisecs and a few megabytes.

Comment: Every layer does add something but it does not have to be performance. For example, a cache layer adds complexity and memory consumption but dramatically improves performance. Also, better design results in better understanding and less replication which can allows developers to reuse, which then makes it attractive to optimize hotspots to be optimized.